# events.js:182 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event and Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, node-modules, stenciljs

I have lost my original node_modules (due to disk wipe) and had to download the theme files and node_modules over again.

I suppose this error is coming form new @babel version 7, but I tried almost everything and it still wont work.

Errors:

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/account.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\account.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/cart.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\cart.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/collapsible.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\collapsible.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/faceted-search.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\faceted-search.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/form-utils.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\form-utils.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/nod-functions/min-max-validate.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\nod-functions\min-max-validate.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/product-details.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\product-details.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/common/state-country.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\common\state-country.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/global/compare-products.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\global\compare-products.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/global/mobile-menu-toggle.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\global\mobile-menu-toggle.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28

ERROR in ./assets/js/theme/global/quick-search.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: F:\[09] backups\zebreo\assets\js\theme\global\quick-search.js: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
    at resolvePath (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:22:24)
    at importModule (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\importModule.js:36:53)
    at memoized (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\memoize.js:62:23)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:217:63
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:193:30
    at arrayEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\lodash\forEach.js:38:10)
    at F:\[09] backups\zebreo\node_modules\babel-plugin-lodash\lib\index.js:181:28
    
    events.js:173
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    TypeError: Expected pattern to be a non-empty string
        at picomatch (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\picomatch\lib\picomatch.js:48:11)
        at createPattern (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:27:18)
        at C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:91:21
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at anymatch (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:91:6)
        at C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:272:51
        at Array.every (<anonymous>)
        at C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:270:22
        at Array.some (<anonymous>)
        at WatchHelper.filterDir (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:269:43)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
        at FSWatcher._handleError (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:647:10)
        at ReaddirpStream.NodeFsHandler._boundHandleError (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:303:43)
        at ReaddirpStream.emit (events.js:196:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)
```

What I tried:

First of all I made sure that I have the upgraded to

```
babel-preset-env
```

and added it as devDependencies

package.json:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ8GI.png

didnt solved the issue.

Then I deleted the

```
node_modules
```

deleted the

```
package-lock.json
```

cleared the cache

```
npm cache clear --force
```

and reinstalled the modules

```
npm install
```

Still not working and throwing the same error.

Do you maybe have an idea what else can I try here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this by moving my directory from

F:[09] backups\zebreo

to

F:\zebreo

seems that the [] was causing the issue

Found the solution here https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash/issues/124#issuecomment-599450158